# Share audio button

Tags: java, android, audio, mp3, share

I am trying to create a Android app, but I am not able to "Share audio .mp3" on a button click. This is my project in java:

```
 Button buonaseeera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pulsantebuonaseeera);
 buonaseeera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {

                     audiobuonaseeera = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
                         R.raw.buonaseeeraaudio);
                     audiobuonaseeera.start();

                     Button sharebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sharebutton);

                     sharebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                 @Override
                                 public void onClick(View v) {
```

What should be the resolution for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `onClick()` of your share button, add the following code:

```
Intent shareAudioIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareAudioIntent.setType("audio/mp3");
shareAudioIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                   Uri.parse("file://"+"path_to_your_mp3_file"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareAudioIntent, "Share MP3 with:"));
```

Just replace the "`path_to_your_mp3_file`" with your audio's path.

**In case, if you want to share a file from resources folder, you have to first copy it to storage and than share the file from storage location.**

Happy codeing. !!!

Comment: Thank you so much. I am going to try it

Comment: It works perfectly, but there is another problem: when I try to share the audio file and I choose the application I want to share it with, There is this message: FILE FORMAT IS NOT SUPPORTED. But it is a normal .mp3 file. What can I do?

Comment: what is the application you are sharing mp3 file with?

Comment: All the apps. Everytime I try to share it, I can't

Comment: How can I share it?

Comment: you can share your code with me directly at mohitum007@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

First of all from my understanding you are trying to share a audio file on a button click. Use this code snippet to share a audio file. just use this in a button click function.

```
String sharePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
            + "your mp3 path";
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(sharePath);
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("audio/*");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Audio File"));
```

Comment: Where you wrote "your path mp3", what should I write? because, if I write the mp3 file's path (R.raw.buonaseeeraaudio), when I use the button in the app, it shows the message: THE FILE FORMAT IS NOT SUPPORTED. Thanks in andvance